# How can I determine if an exception handler was software or hardware triggered?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I just changed my exception handling from `signal` to `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` and now I get software exceptions as well as hardware exceptions. Is there any way that I can determine which is which?

E.g. I just got an exception with exception code `0xE06D7363` which is a result of a c++ throw, not a real hardware exception.

Comment: It's in the [EXCEPTION_RECORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passed to the handler.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Where? The documentation for the ExceptionCode says: `This is the code generated by a hardware exception, *OR* the code specified in the RaiseException function for a software-generated exception.`. So it can be either.

Comment: Right, which is exactly what you need. You need a code that's valid in either case because you don't know which case you're in yet.

Comment: The question is how to determine which one it is: a hardware exception or a software exception.

Comment: One way you can distinguish is to simulate how you expect the hardware to respond, so you can rule that out. You shouldn't even let things get to this if you have developed and debugged step by step.

Comment: @WeatherVane this code is meant for crash reporting. I.e. it sends the crash dump to the server and then exits. this happens in the release build so that I can solve problems that clients are having. the problem is that a software exception shouldnt send a dump because it isnt an error.